# h2 text and bg color flowing while zooming; on Android/Android Emulator 2.2,2.3.3, using jQuery Mobile

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, android-emulator, zooming

For this example, I'm using Android Emulator SDK, version 2.2, with a screen resolution of 480x854.  The page is using jQuery Mobile, as well.

Now, as an example, I have a background color applied to the h2 element.  When I zoom in, the width of the background color shrinks.  I applied a width to the data-role="page" div.  You would think the width would flow down to the other elements inside this div, but it does not.  I have only seen this occur on Android Emulator SDK 2.2 and 2.3.3.  The iPhone does not suffer from this, and I haven't seen this on 4.x, 1.x, or 2.1 of the Android Emulator SDK, either.

When I zoom in, I expect a fixed-width.  I don't want h2, or any element inside the data-role="page" div, to flow to fill the page.  I tried setting a width to h2 in the style, but that didn't help.  As I said, this seems to be only occurring on 2.2 and 2.3.3.  Notice how not only the background of the h2 element flows but the text wraps, too!  I am struggling to find a way to prohibit the text from flowing.

How can I resolve this?

Thank you.

FYI--

Here is the meta name="viewport" tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Here is the CSS for the h2 tag and data-role="page" div:

```
#Index {
  width:320px;
}

h2 {
  background: silver bottom left repeat-x;
  color:#333;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:1em;
  clear:both;
  border-width:2px;
  /*width:320px;*/ /* Does not work */
}
```

Here is the html inside the body tag:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Index">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>

  <a href="JavaScript:history.back();" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-inline="true" class="BackBtn">Back</a>
  <a href="#Index" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-inline="true" class="IndexBtn">Home</a>

  <h2>Section</h2>

</div>
```

Here is a screenshot, zoomed out:

[image: No Zoom]

Here is a screenshot, zoomed in:

[image: Zoomed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conducted some further testing and discovered something rather interesting...

I added inline-block and a fixed-width to the h2 style and expanded it to include h1-h6, p, and div tags (the two aforementioned CSS properties fixed the background color issue).  I displayed each one in HTML with the same set of text.  I noticed that the h3 and h6 text was not flowing/wrapping when zoomed into the page.  The key appears to be adjusting the line-height, which is set at 1.0em for h3 and h6.  I adjusted the line-height to 0.95em for h2 and it remains fixed when zoomed into the page, as well.  So far, it looks okay in Android Emulator SDK 2.1, which didn't have this issue in the first place.  I'll have to test it on other versions and screen resolutions to confirm.

Here's the CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div {
  background: silver bottom left repeat-x;
  width:320px;
  display:inline-block;
}
h3, h6 {
  line-height:1em;
}
h2 {
  line-height:0.95em;
}
```

**Update**

I tested it on other versions and resolutions of the Android Emulator SDK and it looks okay. I also set the line-height to 0.95em for all the block elements above.

New CSS (portrait only)

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div {
  background: silver bottom left repeat-x;
  width:320px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:0.95em;
}
```